Five lights in ceiling controlled by 3switches . Want to take out center light replace w remote fan
Have 5 lights in ceiling. Want to replace center one with fan with remote. Can I wire it to where the fan will be controlled by remote and the other four lights by the three original switches?

Yes. Anything is possible. But it will likely involve running another cable, unless there happens to be "always hot" in the desired location. Only way to tell that is to take a look (both visual and with a multimeter) at the wiring above the existing light fixture.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact some creative use of smart switches and/or smart bulbs may help avoid additional cabling.  It's a shame people provide such little detail in their questions...we don't know if each switch controls one or more bulbs, or if they're 4-way switches, or some combination.
